# How to do coverage on a python coroutine?

Tags: python, code-coverage, tornado, yield, coroutine

I am using tornado coroutines in python 2.7 and I have done unit tests like this one:

```
def test_my_coroutine_function(self):
    # Arranges
    ...

    # Acts
    response = yield my_function()

    # Asserts
    ...
```

My function is defined like that:

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def my_function(self):
    a = True
```

My issue is that coverage.py tell me that the line "a = True" is not covered.

To use coverage, I ran the command line below:

```
coverage run -m --source=./ unittest discover ./; coverage html;
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out how to make it works.

I just have have to replace my unit test by the following:

```
def test_my_coroutine_function(self):
    # Arranges
    ...

    # Acts
    future_response= yield my_function()
    response = future_response.result()

    # Asserts
    ...
```

That's it.